# Nginx: Logging in module

Tags: nginx

How to log in nginx module request handler?

Kindly point to the docs if its already presented elsewhere.

For now:

```
static ngx_int_t ngx_http_printer_hander(ngx_http_request_t* r) {

    // ...
    ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_INFO, r->connection->log, 0, "Hello LOG!");
    // ...
```

I picked this up from the source code. And this works. But this always logs to error.log.

- I'm looking for ways to log to specific log file.
- Some information about creating a custom log object is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Simple hacking around, I found this works:

```
fprintf(stderr, "HELLO_WORLD\n");
```

- But still printing to error.log.
- Still looking for ways to print to custom log file.
- Unsure about the consequence of adding logs that prints directly to files. I guess this should also be part of the event loop of worker.

Perhaps someone could shed some light on this.

Thanks,